# Trying to make a counter everytime I click a button

Tags: php

So basically whenever I click a button the counter will go up and save it to a mysql database. Heres what I have so far but it doesn't echo the number it gives no errors.

```
try {
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabse;charset=utf8', 'myusername', 'password');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
}

if( isset($_POST['clicks']) ) { 
    $sql = "UPDATE clicks SET clicks=clicks+1";
    $result - $db->query($sql);
}

$row = $db->query('SELECT * FROM clicks');

while ($data = $row->fetch()) {
    echo $data["clicks"];
}
```

I don't know if the clicking part works either due to nothing ebing echoed...

The sql table is: Big int 20 clicks

Comment: Are you using a db class if not shouldn't it be $row->fetch($type)? Also why are you looping for one column?

Comment: Did you verify you have records in your database? In the if isset $_POST part, you are not inserting or creating anything, you are updating what is supposed to be there already. Are you sure you have data in the clicks table?

Answer (score 2):

fix this:

```
$result - $db->query($sql);
```

to this:

```
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Good spot, I did not even notice that! +1.

Comment: Nice one.  Hope its fixed?

Comment: It isn't my question, so I can't possibly answer that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont reload the page onclick so echo does not work

Try adding this instead of your echo and see if it works:

```
    $clicks = $data["clicks"];
    echo "<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('$clicks');";
    echo "</script>";
```

Comment: there shoud be an alert poping up. If nothing shows up you probably have an error in your sql. EDIT: there is this:  $result - $db->query($sql); wich might be the issue i think you wanted to write = instead of -